# C# Windows Application: handle large code in one form application with multiple tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I'm going to develop a C# windows application which hosts several tabs in one form. Since components inside each tab are complicated enough, having all codes stored in one file `Form1.cs` is make it hard to handle all methods and code snippets.

I want to know are there any good practices to manage code in such condition?

Comment: Depending on how independent the tabs are, you could design each tab as a separate `UserControl`.

Comment: @adv12 I don't know how it helps to having a clean and readable code. can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes, for my winforms apps eons ago, I would do usercontrol per tab with the Model-View-Presenter pattern. Nowadays, I would use WPF or UWA anyway with MVVM pattern. Winforms still supported but old.

Comment: One possibility is to split the monolithic file up into several separate files.  Each file would be a [Partial Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx#Partial%20Classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made Forms Applications like that before, and I know what you mean about the code getting cumbersome for the `.cs` file.

**Assuming you're not doing this already:**

What I would do is compartmentalize some of the methods and members to separate classes that you call when needed via access operators and/or references.  If you find yourself reusing the same set of lines dozens of times, put it in a `static` method that you can call everywhere without having to declare class objects...  Each `Tab` can call some kind of method like `RunTab1();` that will access the appropriate objects, classes, members and so forth.  This way, when you want to work on Tab2, you can go to that class and ruffle through there, instead of going through one GIANT file looking for one small thing.

I know that sounds like a bit of a generic answer, but I've done it and it worked for me for a multilingual translator among many other things.  Even what I'm working on now - some of the files are over 30k lines and I don't get any lag at runtime.  Hope that helps.